# PowerMock: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: java.lang.Class when mocking java.util.ServiceLoader

Tags: java, testing, static, final, powermock

I am trying to mock the java `ServicesLoader` (which is `final`) in my tests with PowerMock, and it seems to fail...

The simplest test case that reproduces the error is this:

```
import java.util.ServiceLoader;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ServiceLoader.class)
public class ServiceLoaderTest {
    @Test
    public void testServiceLoaderMock() {
        ServiceLoader mock = PowerMock.createMock(ServiceLoader.class);
    }
}
```

And the exception I get is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: ServiceLoaderTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.407 sec <<< FAILURE!
testServiceLoaderMock(ServiceLoaderTest)  Time elapsed: 0.359 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: java.lang.Class
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:56)
        at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:257)
        at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139)
        at org.powermock.core.DefaultFieldValueGenerator.instantiateFieldType(DefaultFieldValueGenerator.java:74)
        at org.powermock.core.DefaultFieldValueGenerator.fillWithDefaultValues(DefaultFieldValueGenerator.java:51)
        at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doMock(PowerMock.java:2146)
        at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.createMock(PowerMock.java:98)
        at ServiceLoaderTest.testServiceLoaderMock(ServiceLoaderTest.java:12)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:322)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:309)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:73)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:297)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:222)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:161)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:135)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:133)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:112)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
```

I guess it has something to do with doing some initialisation of the `Class<T>` field of the service, but I don't know for sure.

Once I have fixed this, I would like also to mock the static method `ServiceLoader.load(Class)` to return the previously created mock, so there might be more problems to come...

Any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a bug. Got the answer from the mailing list:

http://groups.google.com/group/powermock/browse_thread/thread/4afafbfdf1b3ce58

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article: **[Mocking static methods in java system classes](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/05/17/mocking-static-methods-in-java-system-classes/)**, or more specifically, the section called *"But wait, will this work for final system classes?"*.

**Quoted from the article:**

> But what about a final system class? There's no way for PowerMock to remove the final modifier of a system class so what to do? What PowerMock does in these cases is to create a completely new class at run-time with the exact same structure as the original final system class. I.e. all method names and their corresponding signature are copied to a this new replica class. To allow for partial mocking all static methods of the replica class delegates to the original method in the final system class. It's also the replica class that is being mocked by the underlying mock framework instead of the original system class. The MockGateway then figures out that all methods bound for this particular system class should be routed to the replica mock instead. Thus mocking of static methods in final system classes such as java.lang.System or java.lang.String works as well. As a side note it would actually be possible to use this technique to implement duck-typing in Java as well. Anyway, here's an example to demonstrate what we've just said:

```
 public class SystemPropertyMockDemo {

    public String getSystemProperty() throws IOException {
        return System.getProperty("property");
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { SystemPropertyMockDemo.class, SystemPropertyMockDemoTest.class })
public class SystemPropertyMockDemoTest

    @Test
    public void demoOfFinalSystemClassMocking() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(System.class);

        expect(System.getProperty("property")).andReturn("my property");

        replayAll();

        assertEquals("my property",
                                  new SystemPropertyMockDemo().getSystemProperty());

        verifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: still fails while creating the ServiceLoader instance mock (the static mock works fine) :-/